# Why do we identify symmetric 2nd rank tensors with spin-2 particles in string theory?

Tags: special-relativity, string-theory, quantum-spin, group-theory, group-representations

I am going through [Tong's lecture notes on String Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) and came across the following irrep decomposition (Chap 2, p.43) of the bosonic string first excited states:

$$\text{traceless symmetric} \oplus \text{anti-symmetric} \oplus \underbrace{\text{singlet}}_{=\text{trace}}$$

He then goes on and claims that the traceless symmetric tensor is the spin-2 graviton.

What is the reason behind that claim? Is there a relationship between degrees of freedom and the spin of a particle in any number of dimensions? I remember from the $SU(2)$ irrep decomposition that the $\ell=1$ irrep has 3 d.o.f. just like a massive spin-1 particle would have. But what about massless particles living in 26 dimensions?

Comment: Well, the graviton must couple to the totally symmetric rank-2 stress energy tensor, so it must be rank/spin-2, and an anti-symmetric part won't contribute when the Lorentz indexes are contracted with the symmetric stress energy tensor.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14484/2451 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24214/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47547/2451

Comment: @innisfree, the question is actually raised in the context of light-cone quantisation, so the indices are not really Lorentzian.

Comment: In fact, it is an interesting question. Naively, $SO(24)$ corresponds to $D_{12}$ simple Lie algebra, and should have a plethora of inequivalent representations, which cannot be labeled by a single number in an obvious way. Probably, all (corresponding to vector reps of the group, leave spinors alone) arise from tensoring the fundamental rep, hence the "spin-.." names. It would be wonderfull if someone could answer this properly.

Comment: In a $D$ dimensional space-time, a massless particle is a representation of $SO(D - 2)$. The graviton corresponds to the  symmetric traceless representation of $SO(D - 2)$ which has dimension $\frac{D(D - 3)}{2}$

Comment: Flakey language, but you are misreading it. He *explains* in the equation above 2.31 that he is talking about D=4, our space-time embedded in 26, and he is talking about the (4D) particle "in" (as in "embedded in") the 26 dimensions, which goes with spin 2 and the 2 polarization states.  As Trimok says above, the graviton in D=26 has 299 degrees of freedom, and only in D=4 does it have 2.

Answer (score 15):

The spin $s$ of a particle characterizes how the rotation generators act on it. In $D$ dimensions, you represent the little group $SO(D-1)$ for massive particles and $SO(D-2)$ for massless ones. In fact, you really need to consider its universal cover $\textrm{Spin}(n)$ which happen to be just its double cover.

Now, you can define the spin to be the largest real $s$ such that
$$ \mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{2i\pi}{s}J\right) = \rm{id} $$
where $J$ is any generator in your representation. This is basically the statement that, to return to identity, you need to do a $4\pi$ rotation for spin $\frac{1}{2}$, a $2\pi$ for spin 1, a $\pi$ for spin 2... Note that because the universal cover is the double cover, $s$ has to be a half-integer.

It is clear that Lorentz vectors have spin 1. Let's take a symmetric 2-tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$. It transforms as $T'_{\alpha\beta} = R^{\:\,\mu}_{\alpha}R^{\:\,\nu}_{\beta}T_{\mu\nu}$, where $R = \mathrm{exp}(i\theta J)$ are the usual $SO(n)$ matrices.
Infinitesimally, 
\begin{align}
\delta T_{\alpha\beta} & = i\theta(J^{\:\,\mu}_{\alpha}\delta^{\:\,\nu}_\beta + J^{\:\,\nu}_{\beta}\delta^{\:\,\mu}_\alpha)T_{\mu\nu} \\
& = 2  i\theta J^{\:\,\mu}_{\alpha}T_{\mu\beta} \\
\end{align}
where the symmetry of the tensor is crucial.
Now, because $\mathrm{exp}(2i\pi J) = 1$, you see that for $\theta = \pi$, you get back to identity. This is spin 2!

You can generalize this to show that traceless symmetric n-tensors are spin n. You need them to be traceless because you want irreducible representations. With this, it shouldn't be too hard to derive the degrees of freedom of a spin $s$ particle in $D$ dimensions e.g. for the graviton, it is $D(D-3)/2$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The field strength $F$ also transforms with $F'_{\alpha \beta}=R_\alpha^\mu R_\beta^\nu F_{\mu \nu}$, correct? So why does this train of logic not also mean that $F$ is spin-2?

Comment: You are right for the transformation law. $F$ is not spin 2 because it is antisymmetric. The variation of the two indices don't add up as for symmetric tensors. Thus, $F$ has to be considered as a spin 1 field.

Comment: Okay, so that lets you exchange the indices in $T$. Thank you!