# Details on the string theory being a quantum gravity theory

Tags: gravity, string-theory, quantum-gravity, string

So since string theory is a quantum gravity theory, how can we derive from string theory to Einstein gravity equation when $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, as what we did from quantum theory to classical theory? Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Also interesting reads: [In what limit does string theory reproduce general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54317/in-what-limit-does-string-theory-reproduce-general-relativity) and [How do Einstein's field equations come out of string theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44782/how-do-einsteins-field-equations-come-out-of-string-theory)