# String theory and Manifold (elementary question)

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, string, geometry

Why should we think that a space-time in which there are strings is Minkowski space?

I just started studying Polchinski's STRING THEORY. He starts the theory with supposing that the world we live is Minkowski space. When I learned the general relativity, the wrold is a genaral Lorentzian manifold. Can't we start string theory with in a general Lorenzian manifold?

Comment: See section 3.7: "Strings in curved spacetime".

Comment: @Qmechanic Oh, thanks!! I'll read this section and ask again!!!

Comment: @Qmechanic
In this textbook, it seems that he does path integral with respect to induced metric and arrangement of world-sheet. Is it true? If it's true, why shouldn't we path-integrate action with respect to the metric of space-time?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1073/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44732/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I'll check them!!