# How does string theory explain gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, quantum-gravity

I read once that string theory explains gravitation via invoking quanta of the electromagnetic field to transmit the force of gravity over large distances. Is this the truth? I read somewhere else that string theory invokes gravitons and extra dimensions to explain the force of gravity. Since my understanding of string theory isn't excellent, and since it could be an informative exercise, I was wondering if anyone would mind explaining to me exactly how string theory yields gravity in either the Newtonian or relativistic senses.

Comment: I'm afraid that a post on SE would not be enough to explain "exactly" how string theory yields gravity. Besides, do you happen to remember where you have read that "string theory explains gravitation via invoking quanta of the electromagnetic field to transmit the force of gravity"?

Comment: No, I don't. But your best efforts to explain it here (how string theory explains gravity that is) would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know nothing about string theory. I'll wait for someone else to accept the challenge

Comment: see this post and links therein https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30005/how-does-string-theory-predict-gravity

Comment: Thanks, I didn't it all that informative. I was hoping also for something addressing this issue of quanta of electrical fields.

Comment: @SamCottle It has nothing to do with electromagnetism. Perturbative string theory automatically has massless spin-2 particles, and any reasonable theory with interacting massless spin-2 particles has gravity. For a nonperturbative perspective, the AdS/CFT correspondence is the most-studied framework so far. (That's not an answer, just a couple of sentences with keywords to point you in the right direction, because I don't think a one-post answer is feasible.)

Comment: What you might've read is that string theorists make use of dimensional reduction which was originally formalized as part of a different theory by Kaluza and Klein which attempted to unify gravitational and electromagnetic fields back when people thought these were the only two forces.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly even more basic the (assumed) vanishing of the beta functions imply Einstein Field equation (for vacuum)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1073/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54317/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44782/2451 and links therein.